# Trouble understanding non-conservative force and work

Tags: forces, energy, work, potential-energy, conservative-field

I am having some trouble defining whether a [force is conservative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force) or not. In the example that we are working on a mass on a pulley system is used to cause a slender bar to rotate from rest to a certain angle. I know that the tension forces in this case are conservative but I was wondering what force, if any, was non-conservative?

Comment: Friction force.

Comment: Feynman explains all.  http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_14.html

Answer (score 1):

A non conservative force is generally anything that is affected by friction or air resistance. The amount of energy lost is *distance* dependent because the further the path traveled, the more an object is affected by these forces. Conservative forces are *displacement* dependent, meaning they depend only on an initial and final position, and that all the different ways to get between those two points are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example for a non-conservative force is frictional force. For example, to move an object from point A to point B on the table we would require say $10$ J of energy, now to put it back to point A, we would need same $10$ J of energy. Practically nothing observable has changed, but we've performed $20$ J of work, which went to overcome frictional force. So, we may conclude that it is non-conservative. (Since we cannot assign points of potential for it)